# Simple Java IoC container for dependency injection

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, reflection, javafx

I have come up with a quick and simple IoC container to enable minimal dependency injection support in one of my Java projects.

The container supports services with:

- A [transient lifetime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#transient), meaning, a new instance of the service will be created each time they are requested from the container.
- A [singleton lifetime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#singleton), which only creates an instance only once and returns this same instance upon subsequent requests.

Services are registered using the `addService()` method which takes in the types representing the abstraction and the corresponding implementation and the service lifetime.

A service can be requested using the `getService()` method which returns the corresponding service implementation for an abstraction.

Finally, I have an `injectAndConstruct()` method that takes in a client that depends on one or more of these services. It extracts the public constructor of the client and resolves all the dependencies and creates a new instance using this constructor through reflection.

---

#### Code

```
public final class Container {
 
    private final Map<Class<?>, ServiceDescriptor<?, ?>> services = new HashMap<>();

    // holds singleton instances after initial creation
    private final Map<Class<?>, Object> singletonInstances = new HashMap<>();


    public <T> void addService(
          Class<T> abstraction, 
          Class<? extends T> implementation, 
          Lifetime lifetime) {
        validateAbstraction(abstraction);
        validateService(implementation);
        services.put(abstraction, new ServiceDescriptor<>(abstraction, implementation, lifetime));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getService(Class<T> abstraction) {
        var descriptor = (ServiceDescriptor<T, ? extends T>)services.get(abstraction);
        if (descriptor == null) {
            throw new ServiceNotFoundException(abstraction); // custom exception, definition omitted for brevity
        }

        Class<? extends T> implType = descriptor.implementationType();

        
        Constructor<? extends T> publicConstructor = (Constructor<? extends T>) implType.getConstructors()[0];

        return switch(descriptor.lifetime()) {
            case TRANSIENT -> newInstanceOf(publicConstructor);
            case SINGLETON -> {
                // retrieve any existing instance
                T instance = (T) singletonInstances.getOrDefault(abstraction, null);

                // first request: create singleton instance and save to map 
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = newInstanceOf(publicConstructor);
                    singletonInstances.put(abstraction, instance);
                }
                yield instance;
            }
        };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T injectAndConstruct(Class<T> clazz) {
        validateService(clazz);
        Constructor<? extends T> publicConstructor = (Constructor<? extends T>) clazz.getConstructors()[0];
        return newInstanceOf(publicConstructor);
    }

    private <T> T newInstanceOf(Constructor<T> constructor) {
        var parameterTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
        Object[] parameters = new Object[parameterTypes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
            parameters[i] = getService(parameterTypes[i]);
        }

        try {
            return constructor.newInstance(parameters);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }


    private void validateService(Class<?> implementation) {
        if (implementation.getConstructors().length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The service implementation must have exactly one public constructor");
        }
    }

    private void validateAbstraction(Class<?> abstraction) {
        if (!Modifier.isAbstract(abstraction.getModifiers()) && !abstraction.isInterface()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The parameter \"abstraction\" must represent an abstract class or an interface");
        }
    }
}
```

The `ServiceDescriptor` holds information about a service:

```
record ServiceDescriptor<A, I extends A>(
        Class<A> abstractionType,
        Class<I> implementationType,
        Lifetime lifetime) {
}
```

The `Lifetime` enum is to specify the service lifetime:

```
enum Lifetime {
    SINGLETON,
    TRANSIENT
}
```

---

#### Usage

```
Container container = new Container();
container.addService(Service1.class, Service1Impl.class, Lifetime.TRANSIENT);
container.addService(Service2.class, Service2Impl.class, Lifetime.SINGLETON);
Client client = container.injectAndConstruct(Client.class);

class Client {
    public Client(Service1, s1, Service2 s2) { .. }
}

interface Service1 { ... }
interface Service2 { ... }
class Service1Impl implements Service1 { ... }
class Service2Impl implements Service2 { ... }
```

This seems more of a [service locator](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) than injection.

I plan to use this in my JavaFX projects for dependency injection in my FXML controllers.
The [JavaFX FXML loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html) allows setting a controller factory that helps control creation of controller instances. This factory is essentially a [`javafx.util.Callback<Class<?>, Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Callback.html).

The above container allows me to do this:

```
Container container = new Container();
// add services
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(...);
fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(x -> container.injectAndConstruct(MyController.class));
```

And my controller can declare dependencies in the constructor:

```
public class MyController {

    // Injected by factory
    public MyController(Service1 s1, Service2 s2) {..}
}
```

Let me know if there is something I can refactor or improve or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are already robust dependency injection frameworks, like Dagger (compile time injection) and Spring (runtime injection)

Comment: Drop the unchecked annotation: instead `(T) ...` do `abstraction.cast(...)`.

Comment: Seems like a fun exercise.  My only thought was instead of exposing the Lifetime enum, encapsulate that and instead expose addSingleton and addTransient instead of addService.